# How to convert all() function to work crossbrowser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code. I want to convert this as cross browser compatible. As all() is IE only function i need to convert this. Please help me.

```
 for(j=1,oTblRows=tblSource.rows,tLen=oTblRows.length;j<tLen;j++){
    o=oTblRows[j].all("center");        
    if(o && (o.innerText === selCenter.value)){
                  $(oTblRows[j]).show();
    }
    else{
        $(oTblRows[j]).hide();
    }
```

}

Comment: What is `all` supposed to do? You are already using jQuery so why not use it for everything?

Comment: In your case, it should be something like `$(oTblRows[j]).querySelector("center")` which will give you the `<center>` element in the table row or cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.  We want to match all elements with the id of "center" within the current row.

```
o=jQuery("#center", oTblRows[j])
```